Umbraco 7 forms conditional questions issue
Using Umbraco 7 forms - forms v 7.1.4 - it seems I cannot get conditional questions to work for single and multi option radio buttons.  They work fine for conditions dropdowns and text inputs.
I have made sure that ExcludeScripts = "0" is included in the RenderMacro options and included relevant scripts on the FormPicker.cshtml.
Given that this is a legacy site and I can't upgrade, is there anything else I can try to get this to work?
On further testing it seems like changing the radio button value is not firing the evaluation of the radio button. It fires if I update a working conditional.

There are issues described in the Umbraco Forms below 7.2.0 regarding prevalues and conditional fields issues.
You may want to update or patch your Umbraco Forms (not Umbraco) to 7.2.0 or the latest.

